# Elements multiplication in NumPy array with all other elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

If I have a NumPy array [a b c d], is there a way to get the sum of the multiplication of each element with all other elements excluding itself and without duplicates?

For example, the sum for this array would be: *ab* + *ac* + *ad* + *bc* + *bd* + *cd*.

Using for loops is an option, but it wouldn't be very efficient when you have **very** large arrays. So I was wondering if there is a more efficient way in NumPy.

Comment: You can use broadcasting to a square matrix and getting the above diagonal triangle but this will be memory expensive (`O(n^2)`). How large are your arrays?

Comment: 2^N where N<=20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using math, you can refactor the sum of product into a product of sums.

```
a*b + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d + c*d

(a+b+c)*d + (a+b)*c + a*b
```

This gives you the following:

```
out = (a[1:]*np.cumsum(a[:-1])).sum()
```

Or better, use matrix multiplication:

```
out = a[1:] @ a[:-1].cumsum()
```

Example:

```
a = np.array([3, 6, 4, 9, 10])

np.triu(a*a[:,None], k=1).sum()
# 391

a[1:] @ a[:-1].cumsum()
# 391
```

Comment: The sum can be omitted by matrix multiplication: `a[1:] @ a[:-1].cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test of @mozwy's idea of using the upper triangle.

A sample array:

```
In [11]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4]); a,b,c,d = x
```

the sum of products:

```
In [12]: a*b+a*c+a*d+b*c+b*d+c*d
Out[12]: 35
```

The upper tri:

```
In [13]: A = np.triu(np.ones((4,4),int),k=1)    
In [14]: A
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And matrix product:

```
In [15]: x@A@x
Out[15]: 35
```

Another approach, starting with the full outer product:

```
In [17]: outer = x[:,None]*x    
In [18]: outer
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

Remove the trace, and you are left with twice the desired result:

```
In [19]: np.trace(outer)          # or x@x
Out[19]: 30

In [20]: (np.sum(outer)-np.trace(outer))/2
Out[20]: 35.0
```

equivalently using `einsum`:

```
In [25]: (np.einsum('i,j->',x,x)-np.einsum('i,i',x,x))/2
Out[25]: 35.0
```

With `numpy` it is easy, and relatively efficient, to do the full sum of outer products; "vectorization" means doing the whole-array calculations in compiled code, even if means some "extra" work and memory use.

Comment: Yes but the square intermediate is impossible to build if the input has up to 1M items as OP suggested in comment (at least not on my machine :p)